# Does the power level itself have effect in Valhalla or only the selected skills?

Tags: assassins-creed-valhalla

In Assassin's Creed Valhalla you get XP and with these you earn skill points.
When using these skill points on the skill tree you gain power levels.
It is noted in multiple articles that a higher power level makes you stand more damage and do more damage. They also make it sound like there might be some calculations based on the level difference between your power level and the "level" of the opponent.
In multiple RPGs the level itself adds health or other stats, so such a thing is not unheard of.
However, I could not find any direct information about this, so maybe various articles I read are just not worded 100% logically correct.

Example with a tendency to "only skill points matter" (but not clear): [skills guide from ubisoft](https://www.ubisoft.com/en-au/help/assassins-creed-valhalla/gameplay/video/assassins-creed-valhalla-skills-guide-the-best-skills-and-trees-in-acv/6cdbbe51-ef0d-4637-b79f-c62f55e45c67?origin=middle):

> Global Power: Active skill nodes will also increase your overall
> power. This will increase your base Stats and so your ability to
> survive in the world.

Another example that seems like the power level in itself has an effect ([gamepressure](https://guides.gamepressure.com/assassins-creed-valhalla/guide.asp?ID=56249)):

> If you decide to explore a region whose power level significantly
> exceeds the hero's power, you have to remember that:
> Eivor will deal much less damage to enemies, i.e. you will have to
> attack many times to kill them. Enemy attacks will deal Eivor much
> more damage. It is possible that a single enemy attack will kill the
> hero or make them close to dying.

Or [gamertweak](https://gamertweak.com/upgrade-power-levels-assassins-creed-valhalla/):

> With more power level in Assassin’s Creed Valhalla, you will be able
> to take down enemies faster and easier than ever before.

The skill tree perks increase stats like health, light damage and many other things.
The way how the tree works it is basically impossible to put only points in health, or only in damage. So putting a certain amount of skill points ends up raising most stats "somewhat" evenly.
However, you can easily spend 10 points without any effect on a specific encounter and spending 20 points without a bonus to the way you fight.
So having a difference of 20 points between you and the enemy also does not have such a big effect either.

**My question is**:
Does having a higher power level make you stronger (only) because of the exact skill points you selected,
or is there another (additional) direct effect of your power level that increases damage or the amount of damage you can take? (or even the damage that opponents deal)

Of course the power level (regardless of skills selected) adds some green or red color in opponents are when any power level suggestions are displayed, but that is only the graphical effect.

I am also aware that your gear (and the upgrades on it) changes the stats, which is not included in the power level at all.